# How to send a link in mail using PHP

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a link in the mail using PHP but i am not able to format it properly :

```
$message=".<a href=."http://abc.com/viewprofile.php?userid=".$user_id.">"Click here to view user profile"</a>";
```

Comment: Escape the embedded double-quotes? Like `"<a href=\"http://...>"`. If you use an editor with syntax highlighting (or just look at the code snippet in your question here) it should be quite obvious what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes around `href` :

```
$message = "<a href=\"example.com\">Link</a>";
```